# Can two Django Objects have multiple intermediate models between them?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, is it possible to create multiple many to many relationships via multiple intermediate models between two models?

For example, I have an object user and an object stock_position, and every time the user makes a trade, I want to make an intermediate model (transaction) that has user and stock_position as foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock_position = models.ForeignKey(StockPosition,
                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    share = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'stock_position', 'share'),)
```

If you use this *unique index*, you can insert as many user/stock_position duplicates as you want, as long as the `share` column is different each time.  Otherwise an `IntegrityError` will be raised (which you should usually/always have an exception for in your code)

Comment: So yes, the model for transaction would look like you have described, but could you create several of those Transactions with the same foreign key? 
user = User()  
stock_position = StockPosition()  
transaction1 = Transaction(user=user, position=stock_position, share=5)   transaction2 = Transaction(user=user, position=stock_position, share=7)   transaction1.save() transaction2.save()

Comment: @JeffreyHe Yes that should work.  `ForeignKeys` are only unique on the parent table (in this case, the `StockPosition` table).  I would recommend setting up some kind of unique index if you plan on going this route, in order to avoid duplicate data.

Comment: I am not sure of your use case, but I added an example in my answer.